# RScript: how to get the plots saved into multiple files (say png) rather than saved into the Rplots.pdf?

Tags: r, plot, rscript

I use RScript in Windows and by default it saves the plots into the pdf file `Rplots.pdf`, one plot per page.

I would like to get each plot saved into an image file like a `.png`, is it possible?

Comment: @Roland Thank you, I just added `png()` at the beginning of the script to solve the problem.

Comment: I would really appreciate comments from the downvoters in order to improve the question.

Comment: Your question is quite basic and short, with no reproducible example code. That might be the reason.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Thank you for your hints but a possible correct answer (just add `png()` at the beginning of the script) is basic and short too. In this case I do not see the need of a sample code.

Comment: In addition, you do not mention doing any searching yourself. Googling for `R plot png` get's you the answer to your question in the first hit. I answered your question a bit more elaborate than the comment of @Roland.

Comment: I downvoted because you made `zero` effort to do any work at your end. `??function_name` will search base packages and your libraries for any function containing that word. A quick google search would have gotten you an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save your plots as a `png` file, the general idea is:

```
png("spam.png")
plot(...)
dev.off()
```

similar functions are `jpeg` and `tiff`. Wrap all your plots in such calls to `png` to save the plots to specific names. Adding `png()` at the top of the script will save all plots in different png files: `Rplot001.png`, `Rplot002.png`. I would however try and give meaningful names to the plots.

Using Cairo devices, you can use `savePlot`. When you plot with `ggplot2`, the best way imo to save a plot is using `ggsave`.

Comment: Thank you. `png("spam.png")` will save just the last plot.

Comment: Actually, it probably overwrites the plots each time, ending up with only the last one.

Comment: @uvts_cvs - see the bottom of the help page of `?png` for an example of how to build in an iterator into the file name so things don't overwrite themsevles...alternatively - do it directly via a `for` loop or an `apply` function...this is where having some of your code would have been handy :)